# RTE HTML config

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-7.6.x

Since the update of TYPO3 6.2 TYPO3 7.6 appears in RTEHMTL can be in the editor 's own classes for individual styless no longer choose . No new classes more also can be added .
The original configuration comes from a TYPO3 version 4.x , appropriate adjustments by the Install Tool were performed.

Page.TS

RTE-Konfiguration
Angaben zur Ausrichtung (left, center, right) dargestellt und behandelt werden sollen

```
    RTE.classe {
        align-left {
            name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tooltips.xlf:justifyleft
            value = text-align: left;
        }
        align-center {
            name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tooltips.xlf:justifycenter
            value = text-align: center;
        }
        align-right {
            name = LLL:EXT:rtehtmlarea/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tooltips.xlf:justifyright
            value = text-align: right;
        }
    }
```

Wenn in der Basiskonfiguration die Option 'Enable links accessibility icons' aktiviert ist, werden nach dem Setzen eines Links im RTE kleine Icons vor diesem plaziert. Durch Löschen oder ändern des Parameters 'RTE.classesAnchor.internalLink.image' können die Bilder gelöscht oder geändert werden.

```
RTE.classesAnchor {
    internalLink {
        class = internal-link
        type = page
        titleText = Eigene Seite
        image = fileadmin/system/bild/link01.gif
    }
    internalLinkInNewWindow {
        class = internal-link--new-window
        type = url
        titleText = Eigene Seite im neuen Fenster
    }
    externalLink {
        class = external-link
        type = url
        titleText = Fremde Seite
    }
    externalLinkInNewWindow {
        class = external-link-new-window
        type = url
        titleText = Fremde Seite im neuen Fenster
    }
    download {
        class = download
        type = file
        titleText = Download
    }
}
```

// Anpassung für tt_news

```
RTE.config.tt_news.bodytext.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
```

// Anpassung für tx_news

```
RTE.config.tx_news.bodytext.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
```

Default-Konfiguration

```
RTE.default {
    //  Konfiguration des Rechtschreibprüfung
    defaultContentLanguage = de
    buttons {
        spellcheck {
            enablePersonalDictionaries = 1
            dictionaries.items = de
            dictionaries.restrictToItems = de
        }
    }
    schema {
        sources {
            schemaOrg = EXT:rtehtmlarea/extensions/MicrodataSchema/res/schemaOrgAll.rdf
    }
    //  Der Inhalt im RTE lässt sich getrennt mit einem Stylesheet versehen, das
    //  hier angegeben wird
    contentCSS = fileadmin/code/css/rte.css
    //  Beim Kopieren von Text aus Textverarbeitungen werden nicht nur sichtbarer Text
    //  sondern auch unsichtbare Formatierungen mitgenommen, was zu unerwünschten For-
    //  maten im RTE führt. Durch diesen EIntrag wird versucht diese Steuerzeichen
    //  weitestgehend zu entfernen. 
    enableWordClean = 1
    //  Hier wird ein <br> am Textanfang entfernt
    removeTrailingBR = 1
    //  Entfernen von HTML-Kommentaren aus dem Quelltext. Dies ist hilfreich, wenn
    //  man Text aus HTML-Seiten kopiert und damit u.U. auch unsichtbare HTML-Kommentare
    //  mitkopiert hat.
    removeComments = 1
    //  Entfernt nachfolgende Tags, wenn von der Quelltextansicht in den HTML-Modus
    //  gewechselt wird.
    removeTags = center, font, o:p, sdfield, strike, u
    //  Folgende Tags UND deren Inhalt werden entfernt
    removeTagsAndContents = style,script
    //  Buttons, die in der RTE-Oberfläche angezeigt werden sollen
    //  Die Position gibt zugleich die Reihenfolge an.
    // showButtons = textstyle, textstylelabel, blockstyle, blockstylelabel, formatblock, bold, italic, underline, , subscript, superscript, left, center, right, justifyfull, orderedlist, unorderedlist, insertcharacter, line, link, removeformat, spellcheck, chMode, table, toggleborders, tableproperties, rowproperties, rowinsertabove, rowinsertunder, rowdelete, rowsplit, columninsertbefore, columninsertafter, columndelete, columnsplit, cellproperies, cellinsertbefore, cellinsertafter, celldelete, cellsplit, cellmerge, findreplace, insertcharakter, undo, redo, showhelp, about,inserttag
    // Buttons, die nicht in der RTE Oberfläche angezeigt werden
    // hideButtons = fontsytle, fontsize, strikethrough,leftorright, rightorleft, textcolor, bgcolor, textinicator, emoticon, user, inserttag, outdent, indent, subscript, superscript, abbreviation, copy, cut, paste, image
    //  Bewirkt, dass Buttons, die zu einer Gruppe gehören, in einer Zeile angezeigt werden. Gruppen werden durch senkrechte Striche getrennt
    //keepButtonGruoupTogether = 1
    //  Zeigt unterhalb des RTE-Eingabefeldes eine Statusleiste an, in der die Schachtelung der Tags angezeigt wird
    showsStatusBar = 1
    //  Inline-Styles für die Ausrichtung in Absätzen und Tabellenzeilen hinzufügen
    contentCSS.text-alignment = p.align-left, h1.align-left, h2.align-left, h3.align-left, h4.align-left, h5.align-left, h6,align-left, td.align-left, p.align-center, h1.align-center, h2.align-center, h3.align-center, h4.align-center, h5.align-center, h6,align-center, td.align-center, p.align-right, h1.align-right, h2.align-right, h3.align-right, h4.align-right, h5.align-right, h6,align-right, td.align-right, span.werktitel, span.actor, span.regie span.important

    //  Hier wird die Transformation zwischen RTE und Datenbank konfiguriert
    //  Alle Tags, die überhaupt erlaubt sind, und damit in die Datenbank geschrieben werden dürfen
    proc {
        allowTags = table, tbody, tr, th, td, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, p, br, span, ul, ol. li, pre, blockquote, strong, em, b, i, u, sub, strike, a, img, nobr, hr, tt, q, cite, abbr, abbreviation, center
    //  Da diese Teags in der DB nicht erlaubt sind, werden diese auch nichtin die DB geschrieben, sondern entfenrt
        denyTags = font
        //  Wenn <br> nicht automatisch zu <p> umgewandelt werden soll, muss an dieser Stelle der Wert 1 gesetzt werden
        dontConvBRtoParagraph = 1
        // Wandelt das & in &nbsp; und nicht &amp;nbsp um
        //    dontConvAmpInNBSP_rte = 0
        //Lediglich folgende Tags sind außerhalb von <p> und <div> erlaubt
        allowtagsOutsite = img, hr
        //  Folgende Attribute sind innerhalb von <p> und <div> erlaubt. Alles andere wird entfernt
        keepPDIVattribs = align, class, style, id
        //  Folgende Klassen sind prinzipell erlaubt
        allowedClasses = external-link, external-link-new-window, internal-link, internal-link-new-window, download, mail, alingn-left, align-center, align-right, author, werktitel, actor, randtext, buch1, buch2    
        //  Fügt das Media-Feld von DAM dem RTE hinzu
        overruleMode = ts_css
        //  Modifiziert Link-Button im HTMLrte
        // Generelle EInstellungen für den HTML-Parser
        HTMLparser_rte {
            // Transformationsanpassungen werden kopiert
            allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
            denyTags < RTE.default.proc.denyTags
            // Diese Tags werden direkt entfernt
            removeTags = font
            // Entfernt HTML-Kommentare
            removeComments = 1
            // Tags die nicht richtig verschachtelt sind, werden entfernt
            keepNonMatchingTags = 0
        }
        // Transformationsweg: Vom RTE in die DB
        entryHTMLparser_db = 1
        entryHTMLparser_db {
        // Liste der erlaubten und nicht erlaubten Tags wird kopiert
        allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
        denyTags < RTE.default.proc.denyTags
        //  Tags für die keine Attribute erlaubt sind
        noAttrib = b, i, u, strike, sub, sup, strong, em, quote, blockquote, cite, tt, br, center
        //  Tags werden entfernt, wenn sie keine Attribute aufweisen
        rmTagIfNoAttrib = span, div, font
        //  Sonderzeichen werden in Entities ungewandelt
        htmlSpecialChars = 1
        //  Align-Attribute werden erlaubt
        tags {
            p.fixAttrib.align.unset >
            p.allowedAttribs = class, style, align, span
            div.fixAttrib.align.unset >
            hr.allowedAttribs = class
            span.allowAttribs = class
            // Setzt bei internen Links den Seitentitel standardmäßig
            // a.fixAttrib.href.userFunc = fileadmin/system/scripte/class.user_settitle.php:user_settitle->geturl
            // a.fixAttrib.href.always = 1
            // a.fixAttrib.title.userFunc = fileadmin/system/scripte/class.user_settitle.php:user_settile->settitle
            // a.fixAttrib.title.always = 1
            //  <b>/<i> Tags werden ersetzt in </em>/<strong>
            b.remap = strong
            i.remap = em
            //  <img>-Tag wird erlaubt
            img >
        }
    }
    //  Transformationsweg: Vom RTE in die DB
    exitHTMLparser_db = 1
    exitHTMLparser_db {
      //  <b>/<i>-Tags werden durch <strong>/<em> ersetzt
      tags.b.remap = strong
      tags.i.remap = em
      //  Alle noch verhandenen Tags, die kein Matching besitzen werde an dieser STelle
      //  behalten, da die unerwünschten Tags ohnehin beim Entry schon gefiltert wurden.
      keepNonMatchedTags = 1
      //  Dppelte Umwandlung von Sonderzeichen wird hier verhindert
      htmlSpecialChars = 0
    }
  }
  //  Folgende Klassen zur Auszeichnung von Absätzen sind erlaubt
  buttons.blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses {
    align-left, align-center, align-right
  }
  //  Zeigt CSS-Klassen an, die im Stylesheet noch nicht zugewiesen wurden
  showTagsFreeClasses = 1
  //  Folgende Tags dürfen generell nicht eingefügt werden
  hideTags = font
  // Tabellen-Optionen in der RTE-Toolbar
  hideTableOperationsInToolbar = 0
  keepToggleBordersInToolBar = 1
  // Tabellen-Editierungs-Optionen (Cellspacing/cellpadding/border)
  disableSpacingFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
  disableAlignmentFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
  disableColorFieldsetInTableperations = 1
  disableLayoutFieldsetInTableOperations = 1
  disableBordersFieldsetInTableOperations = 0

  enableWordClean.HTMLparser < RTE.default.proc.enttyHTMLparser_db

  //  RTE-Verarbeitung in der Bodytext-Spalte von tt_content.
  tt_content.bodytext {
    proc.overruleMode = ts_css
    types.text.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
    types.textpic.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
  }

  // FE Konfiguration (wird bei der Nutzung des RTE beim FE-Editing benötigt)
  FE < RTE.default
  FE.userElements >
  FE.userLinks >
  // Nutzt die gleiche Form bei der Ausgabe im FE
  FE.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
}
```

Does anyone have an idea? ?

Comment: Yes please update your question and add your code!

Comment: Ok Georg, here is the PageTS.